# Are the results of Flink window aggregations (and other operations) persisted in snapshots?

Tags: apache-flink

For example, if I window some data and .aggregate, is the aggregator I’ve created reset if the system goes down?

Comment: Hey, could You specify Your question a little bit? What do You mean by aggregator exactly? Generally, when the aggregator aggregates the data from the window this data is emitted further to the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Flink, the state in windows and aggregators is included in checkpoints and is restored in the event of a failure/restart. The same is true of all of Flink's stateful operations.